# Docker Compose unable to find Maven pom

Tags: maven, docker, docker-compose

While playing around with the code example at https://github.com/hellokoding/hellokoding-courses/tree/master/docker-examples/dockercompose-springboot-mysql-nginx, I am stuck while trying to run the docker compose (using the command `docker-compose up`). Looks like the images are created fine, but inside the app image the Maven command fails as the pom.xml is not found.

```
C:\Dev\sandbox\hellokoding-courses\docker-examples\dockercompose-springboot-mysql-nginx>docker-compose up --build
Building app
Step 1/1 : FROM adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk8
 ---> f167b3a06c25
Successfully built f167b3a06c25
Successfully tagged dockercompose-springboot-mysql-nginx_app:latest
Starting my-mysql ... done
Recreating my-app ... done
Recreating my-nginx ... done
Attaching to my-mysql, my-app, my-nginx
my-mysql | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.26-1.1.11
my-app   | [INFO] Scanning for projects...
my-app   | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
my-app   | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
my-app   | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
my-app   | [INFO] Total time:  0.564 s
my-app   | [INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-17T08:23:53Z
my-app   | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
my-app   | [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/app). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
my-app   | [ERROR]
my-app   | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
my-app   | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
my-app   | [ERROR]
my-app   | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
my-app   | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

I am not getting the problem as the app folder is mapped via Volume and should be available to the compose. I also tried to copy the "app" folder inside the app DockerFile so that it reflects in the image (and I verified that it does using the command `docker run -it dockercompose-springboot-mysql-nginx_app sh`) but that didn't help either.

Following are the content of the DockerFile inside the simple SpringBoot app:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk8
#Following was added by me, wasn't part of the Github code
COPY . /app
```

And following is the compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
   container_name: my-nginx
   image: nginx:1.13
   restart: always
   ports:
   - 80:80
   - 443:443
   volumes:
   - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
   depends_on:
   - app

  mysql:
   container_name: my-mysql
   image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
   environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: hellokoding
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
   ports:
   - "3306:3306"
   restart: always

  app:
    container_name: my-app
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    expose:
      - "8080"
    command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with maven, but you should be able to `docker-compose run app bash` (or `sh` instead of `bash`)? And from there, see if /app contains what you expect it to.

Comment: Great comment @petre, thanks. I did that and strangely the "app" directory was empty. I then removed the volume mapping for app and it worked (with the COPY command that I had added to DockerFile earlier).

Answer (score 0):

Does your `pom.xml` resides in /app directory. As per your config it should.

You can also specify exact location of `pom.xml` using `-f` option.

```
mvn -f /path/to/pom.xml clean spring-boot:run
```